# API to gather transaction fees for a random subset of transactions

Tags: transactions, etherscan, ethereumjs, explorer-api

I wish to do something that may be relatively trivial but I do not understand how I would go about it.

This is for my thesis project and I would like to demonstrate that Ethereum has high transaction fees, I wish to do this, by taking some random N transactions in the blockchain and noting the transaction fee.

The issue, I do not know any APIs that will give me the last 1,2,3....N number of transactions that have occurred on the said blockchain.

Essentially, when I visit Etherscan.com, I would like to

[image]

Access these transactions programmatically and then

Retrieve the transaction fee paid for each of the transactions on this list.

How would I approach this?

Comment: You could get the transaction from the last blocks.